# Javascript "SyntaxError: Unexpected token else"

Tags: javascript

Okay so I have searched this up and looked over my code multiple times but I can't seem to figure out what's causing this. It seems like it usually happens when someone puts a semicolon after an if statement but I don't have any after any if statements (unless I'm blind or something) so I don't know. I'm coding a simple Discord bot using Javascript and node.js. Whenever I go into Terminal to start up the bot I keep getting this error:

> /Users/Nyro/Desktop/Thax/digger.js:64
>         else
>         ^^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
>       at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
>       at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
>       at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

(I'm not sure if all the things under it are important or not to the error but they're there). 
Also line 64 is the same as a lot of other lines in the code (since a lot of it is repetitive for different words) so I don't know why it seems to be focused on that area. Anyway, here is the code in that area:

```
if ((messageauthor == botname) == false){ // to prevent spamming to oblivion

   if (dofilter('cupcake'))
   {
      sendimpeccablemessage('Message1');
   } 
   else

   if (dofilter('linus'))
   {
      if (Math.floor(Math.random()*3))
         {sendimpeccablemessage('Message2');}
      else
         {sendimpeccablemessage('Message3');}
      else
         {sendimpeccablemessage('Message4');}
   } 
   else
```

I got this code from a screenshot my friend took while testing the code (but he never actually sent me the file). This isn't the full code but just the one part it seems to have an issue with, but the rest of the code is basically the same thing (some have random choices while others don't).

Answer (score 2):

You have two else statements here:

```
if (Math.floor(Math.random()*3))
     {sendimpeccablemessage('Message2');}
  else
     {sendimpeccablemessage('Message3');}
  else
     {sendimpeccablemessage('Message4');}
```

The middle should be an `else if` or remove the last.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 else statements.  You can do if/else if/else, but you can't do if/else/else.

```
if (Math.floor(Math.random()*3))
         {sendimpeccablemessage('Message2');}
else
         {sendimpeccablemessage('Message3');}
else
         {sendimpeccablemessage('Message4');}
```

The formatting is also confusing. I always put brackets in, as this shows the execution order.

```
if ((messageauthor == botname) == false) { 
    // to prevent spamming to oblivion
  if (dofilter('cupcake')) {
      sendimpeccablemessage('Message1');
  } 
  else {
    if (dofilter('linus')) {
          if (Math.floor(Math.random()*3)) {     
               sendimpeccablemessage('Message2');
          }
          else {
               sendimpeccablemessage('Message3');
           }
          //else{
          //     sendimpeccablemessage('Message4');}
       }    

  }
} 
else {

}
```

[Why I put brackets in.](http://structuredsight.com/2014/03/09/brackets/)

Comment: why do you have the same problem in your answer that exists in the question?